# Hardcoding large amounts of data without inducing memory spike

Tags: javascript, webassembly, deno

So I am exploring the concept of storing WebAssembly inside the JavaScript file so it can all be bundled up in one shippable file. I did manage to make a working example of this where it stores the wasm file in a big literal string in base64 and at runtime is converted to a Uint8Array before being processed into a Module and Instance.

```js
await Deno.writeTextFile(
    './static/wasm/bundle.js',
    `import { initSync } from './app.js'\ninitSync(new WebAssembly.Module(Uint8Array.from(atob('${btoa(
        [ ...await Deno.readFile('./static/wasm/app_bg.wasm') ]
            .map(byte => String.fromCharCode(byte))
            .join('')
    )}').split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)))))`
)
```

*[Source of above snippet](https://github.com/BlackAsLight/BundleWasm)*

But I have been wondering if JavaScript might have problems with processing this literal string in instances that the wasm file was very large. In this snippet the base64 literal string is only needed once at the very start, and I imagine is disposed off by the garbage collector as it's no longer accessible.

I am wondering if people have any ideas on how one could store this same type of data, hardcoded in the javascript, where it is only run once, but won't causes any huge memory spikes at the start of the runtime. Increased processing time for reduced peak memory usage is an acceptable trade-off here, but fetching any external resources would defeat the point of the question.

Comment: This seems like asking "I want to have all my belongings in one bag but I don't want the bag to be heavy". I tought about unzipping the base64 string, like with [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/), but then you would have the compressed, the base64 and the running version in memory. What are your ideas of very large? In terms of megabytes wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: In terms of large, I don't have a definitive answer, but I'd say anything that caused a noticeable lag spike in the responsiveness in the browser. Since I believe all of this code in run in sync, a lag spike is very possible.

I was trying to think of ways that instead of having it be a huge literal string, it instead be consumed in parts, trying to leverage the interpretive nature of JavaScript.

Comment: Do you have data on the lag spikes / responsiveness behavior? Do you have a minimum hardware to target? The code could still load and run in less than a second or even less, based on how large the wasm files are. Could you load the wasm file directly? There is a lot back&forth going on with `btoa` of an `atob` result, coming from `map`, `join` and `split` and `map` calls which looks like redundant transformations.

Comment: @Dr.Light I added 3 alternatives that should reduce memory and should be faster (excluding network), but please let me know the results once you do your benchmarks

Comment: If perceived browser lag is the issue use a worker. *(Oh, this is Deno, and I don't know if workers have access to this, but just in case, I'll leave this.)*

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't think he's using the bundle in Deno, he's just generating the bundle with Deno by checking the repo.

Comment: The advantage of putting it in a separate file is that it can be cached by the browser, allowing you to change the main page without reloading the wasm.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I don't actually have an wasm file that is big enough to be causing lag spikes. I'm just exploring possible options if such a thing did occur. It's really just an experimental exercise.

Comment: @DaveNewton Deno is simply being used to embed the wasm inside the javascript. The wasm isn't run inside Deno, but instead the browser. The linked repo is set up to work with the Live Server extension for VSCode. Deno is nothing more but a building tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following will reduce memory usage and load faster (CPU wise), but will result in a bigger file.

```js
function toUint8ArrayString(u8) {
    return `new Uint8Array([${u8.join(',')}])`;
}

const wasmData = toUint8ArrayString(await Deno.readFile('./app_bg.wasm'));

await Deno.writeTextFile('./static/wasm/bundle.js', `import { initSync } from 'app.js'\ninitSync(new WebAssembly.Module(${wasmData}))`)
```

Instead of having the data in `base64` you generate the array data to be used directly in the `Uint8Array` constructor.

From:

```js
const init = atob('YQ==').split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)); // [97]
Uint8Array.from(init);
```

To

```js
new Uint8Array([97]); // or Uint8Array.from([97]);
```

By doing this, you're avoiding `atob`, `.split`, `.map`, `.join` with all the copies being done by these methods under the hood.

---

For large amounts of data, the best would be to use `fetch` and `base64` encoded data:

```
const url = "data:application/wasm;base64," + b64wasm;
// Your bundle should produce the final url string
// const url = "data:application/wasm;base64,YQo=";
const res = await fetch(url);
const u8wasm = new Uint8Array(await res.arrayBuffer());
const module = new WebAssembly.Module(u8wasm);
```

And if supported, you can even use [`WebAssembly.compileStreaming`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/JavaScript_interface/compileStreaming) which should result in the lowest amount of memory usage.

```js
const url = "data:application/wasm;base64," + b64wasm;
// Your bundle should produce the final url string
// const url = "data:application/wasm;base64,YQo=";

const module = await WebAssembly.compileStreaming(fetch(url));
```

Comment: Your second suggestion does seem to be a better way all around to do it than I am currently doing it, as it can probably leverage the native code behind fetch to convert the base64 back to a binary. I am bound by the `app.js` file due to the way I am producing the wasm code and the requirement of the imports object.

`await Deno.writeTextFile('./static/wasm/bundle.js', \`import x from './app.js'\nx(fetch('data:application/wasm;base64,${btoa([ ...await Deno.readFile('./static/wasm/app_bg.wasm') ].map(byte => String.fromCharCode(byte)).join('')) }'))\`)`

Comment: You can use `import { encode} from "https://deno.land/std@0.201.0/encoding/base64.ts"` instead of `btoa`, `.map` & `String.fromCharCode` btw